# Looking for pure javascript image color analysis

Tags: javascript, image, colors

I'm trying to set up a gallery of images that come one by one as you click the webpage. The image is displayed upfront, with a blurred version of that image as the background. But I'm finding that blur filters don't work on IE, and cause problems elsewhere. So I'm wanting an alternative for IE where the background color sets to whatever the dominant color cluster is, in hexadecimal preferably, where I can get it as a variable and supply it into a CSS change via javascript. Preferably, there would be five clusters of pixels, and the one with the highest percentage would be chosen. I'm not sure how these clusters are calculated, but I use this tool to manually get color information from images one by one, on default settings, which works perfectly:

http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/color-summarizer/?examples

I just wish I had an automation in my own javascript.

I feel like Color Thief could be of use to me, but I apparently just don't understand how to use it or write the script to employ it I mean. I'm very new to this. Been coding for about four days. Any help with that would be very very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not my script, but I can't find the source anymore. It returns the dominant color of a (locally hosted) image.

```
  function getAverageRGBa(imgEl, a) {
      var a = a || 1;

      var blockSize = 5, // only visit every 5 pixels
          defaultRGB = {r:0,g:0,b:0}, // for non-supporting envs
          canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
          context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d'),
          data, width, height,
          i = -4,
          length,
          rgb = {r:0,g:0,b:0},
          count = 0;

      if (!context) {
          return defaultRGB;
      }

      height = canvas.height = imgEl.naturalHeight || imgEl.offsetHeight || imgEl.height;
      width = canvas.width = imgEl.naturalWidth || imgEl.offsetWidth || imgEl.width;

      context.drawImage(imgEl, 0, 0);

      try {
          data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
      } catch(e) {
          /* security error, img on diff domain */
          return defaultRGB;
      }

      length = data.data.length;

      while ( (i += blockSize * 4) < length ) {
          ++count;
          rgb.r += data.data[i];
          rgb.g += data.data[i+1];
          rgb.b += data.data[i+2];
      }

      // ~~ used to floor values
      rgb.r = ~~(rgb.r/count);
      rgb.g = ~~(rgb.g/count);
      rgb.b = ~~(rgb.b/count);

      return 'rgba(' + rgb.r + ', ' + rgb.g + ', ' + rgb.b + ', ' + a + ')';
  }
```

*Edit:* May have found the source: https://jsfiddle.net/xLF38/

Comment: Wow this looks like it could be rather useful, albeit complex to me. My images are actually non-local, but hopefully it still works. What is `imgEl` and `a` referring to? ID's, sources, or... and I'm not sure what `a` is.

Comment: Oh, I was just looking at that fiddle. It's based on an averaging rather than dominant color. Meaning if you have slightly more deep blues than deep greens, you'll end up with cyan or something rather the deep blue.

Comment: Damn I tried it because average is better than nothing and it's returning the correct value for locally hosted images but not for anything hosted by someone else. I think. Or maybe it's just the order in which the image is being replaced within my function. My code is a little complex for me to understand, with how I got a lot of trial and error working.

Comment: It even says so in the code `/* security error, img on diff domain */`